# Why is $Mac_k(m_1||m_2) = ⟨F_k(m_1), F_k(m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2})⟩$ not a secure MAC?

Tags: mac, pseudo-random-function

I am preparing for an exam and trying to solve the following question I found on the internet:

> Let $F_k$ be a pseudorandom function. Show that the following MAC for messages of length $2n$ is insecure. The shared key is a random key $k \in \{0, 1\}^n$.
>
> $\operatorname{Mac}_k(m_1||m_2) = ⟨F_k(m_1), F_k(m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2})⟩$
>
> where $m_1, m_2$ are binary strings of length $n$ and $\overline{m_2}$ is $m_2$with all its bits inverted. What is the minimum number of queries that the adversary has to make to the MAC-oracle to forge a MAC?

To solve both questions I have tried to construct two messages for which the attacker requests tags and then combine the messages and corresponding tags in a way that gives a valid message and tag. Regrettably, this didn't work out since the second part of the tag combines both parts of the original message. Am I on the wrong track with my approach?

Comment: what does minimum means though? this is randomised as far as i can tell so if an adversary is really really lucky he could forge a mac with one query.

Comment: If you can provide a way to forge a tag with requesting only a single tag that should be a legitimate answer. But how would you do that? I am looking for a concrete solution how to forge a valid message and tag.

Comment: As i said this is randomised. You can not say the exact numbers of queries needed, not even the minum numbers because even if you try random strings as a mac you may well forge a mac on your first try.

Comment: @mandragore In what way is this randomized? In addition, being able to forge a mac on your first try with low probability doesn't matter.

Comment: $⟨x,y⟩$ is supposed to be a tuple?

Comment: I can do this in two queries.

Comment: @mandragore I think the question is asking for the minimum number of queries you need for a guaranteed forgery.

Comment: @YehudaLindell Indeed it will happen with low probabilty but that is exactly my point. It is possible to forge a mac with 1 query. That is why i wanted clarification on the meaning of minimum numbers.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yeah you are probably right.

Comment: @mandragore The meaning is clearly the minimal while succeeding with "good" probability (non-negligible probability).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We want to forge the tag for $m = m_1 || m_2$. The tag we need to produce is:

$$\operatorname{Mac}_k(m_1||m_2)=⟨F_k(m_1), F_k(m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2})⟩$$

We'll query the oracle with the message $m_1^\prime || m_2^\prime$, which needs to be different from $m_1||m_2$ to count as forgery. Consider $m_1^\prime || m_2^\prime = (m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2}) || m_2$, which is different from $m_1||m_2$ iff $\overline{m_2} \neq 0$.

This message has the tag:

$$\begin{align}
  \operatorname{Mac_k(m_1^\prime||m_2^\prime)}
  &=⟨F_k(m_1^\prime),F_k(m_1^\prime \oplus \overline{m_2^\prime})⟩ \\
  &=⟨F_k(m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2}),F_k((m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2})\oplus \overline{m_2})⟩ \\
  &=⟨F_k(m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2}),F_k(m_1)⟩
\end{align}$$

swapping the two outputs produces the tag for $m=m_1||m_2$.

Thus we can produce forgeries using only a single query to the MAC oracle.

Comment: Cool! This is a very nice answer.

Comment: The tag for $m\prime$ is $<F_k(m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2}), F_k( m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2} \oplus \overline{m_1})> =<F_k(m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2}), F_k(m_2)> $. And then you can get a tag for $m = m_2 || m_1$

Comment: @mandragore Fixed.

Comment: To make sure that I understood it correctly: I request a tag for message $m = m_1 || m_2$ which gives me $t = ⟨t_1, t_2⟩$. My forged message and tag are $m' = (m_1 \oplus \overline{m_2})||m_2$, $t = ⟨t_2, t_1⟩$. Correct?

Comment: @Lemon I explained it the other way round (querying $m^\prime$ and forging $m$), but that works as well.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. Thanks! That is indeed a really nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $m_1 = 0^n || 0^n$, then:
$$Mac_k(0^n || 0^n) = <F_k(0^n), F_k(0^n \oplus1^n)> \\
 = <F_k(0^n), F_k(1^n)>$$

Now consider $m_2 = 0^n || 1^n$, then:
$$Mac_k(0^n || 1^n) = <F_k(0^n), F_k(0^n \oplus 0^n)> \\
 = <F_k(0^n), F_k(0^n)>$$

so you would not even have to query for $m_2$ as you already know the output would be the first part of $m_1$ twice. This is a break of security.